# How to get the inverse value based on a set of running numbers in php?

Tags: php

For example, if I have N running numbers, e.g. 1 to 7 or 1 to 8.

On left is what I have and on right I want to be converted to:

```
1 - 7
2 - 6
3 - 5
4 - 4
5 - 3
6 - 2
7 - 1

1 -> 8
2 -> 7
3 -> 6
4 -> 5
5 -> 4
6 -> 3
7 -> 2
8 -> 1
```

is there an easy algorithm to do this?

Note: that I do not readily have the whole array, but I do have the "base" of 7 or 8 in the examples above which of cause could be used to generate the array if that's really needed.

If it helps my use case is this. I have a function which gives me back an integer value between 1-7 but in same cases I need to inverse (not even sure that's the right word) the value (e.g. getting a 2 means it should be converted to a 6).

Comment: from a function returning just an integer between 1-7. of cause i could write a 7 if statements to convert it. but is there a "quick" function that already does that?

Comment: Are you looking for [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)?

Comment: i don't have the array just a integer value between 1 - 7 is return to me. does that mean i have to create the whole arrange every time and then use array_flip? is there really no algorithm to convert 1 to 7 and 2 to 6 without using an array?

Comment: Are you looking for [`this`](https://3v4l.org/juFYd)? Cause its pretty unclear what you want to convey and achieve

Comment: ok say the range is from 13 to 37... when i get 13 i want it to become 37. when i get 37 i want it to become 13. all i know is there are 24 numbers in the range. can i do something like "24-13 * x" and magically convert it? sorry i suck at math.

Comment: I think [`this`](https://3v4l.org/UvVN0) is what you want to achieve

Comment: yes, that's closest to what i want to achieve. create as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually you need to define the `array` first and then `reverse` the array and `combine` the whole array as `key value pair` so your code look like as

```
$main_arr = range(13,37);
$reversed_arr = array_reverse($main_arr);

$arr = array_combine($main_arr,$reversed_arr);

echo $arr[13].PHP_EOL; //37

echo $arr[37].PHP_EOL; //13

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Explaination

I'm using here a static method to make it easier to use, but feel free to implement it the way you want.

The idea is just to play with the indexes of an array. If your array is undetermined, you'll have to find a solution to create that array in order to use it. But you got my point.

#### Solution

```
<?php

class Reverse {

    private static $arrayBase8 = [ 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ];
    private static $arrayBase7 = [ 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];

    public static function base8($number) {

        if ($number < 1) {

            return 0;

        }

        return self::$arrayBase8[$number - 1];

    }

    public static function base7($number) {

        if ($number < 1) {

            return 0;

        }

        return self::$arrayBase7[$number - 1];

    }

}

echo Reverse::base8(5);
echo '<br>';
echo Reverse::base7(5);
```

#### Output

```
4
3
```

#### Documentation

[Online demo](http://phpio.net/s/2724).

[PHP: array_reverse()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

Comment: This is a valid approach, but it does not really answer the question, it gives a _hint_ on _how to_ solve the task.

Comment: Sorry, but you now changed your answer completely and, sorry to say so, but the current version is, well, questionable. Whilst it probably works in a certain way (still not really answering what the OP asked...) it is very ineffective... It does _not_ output a series of numbers but only a single pair for each call. Further: why do you need two separate arrays if the contain nothing but a decrementing series of integers? You could easily work with a single one. And why do you use two separate methods? Why not implement a static base value set in the constructor and compute the rest?

Answer (score -1):

Well, just loop over an incrementing variable until you reach the base:

```
<?php
$base = 7;
for ($i=1; $i<=$base; $i++) {
  echo sprintf("%d - %d".PHP_EOL, $i, $base-$i+1);
}
```

An alternate approach would be that:

```
<?php
$base = 7;
for ($i=1; $i<=$base,$j=$base-$i+1; $i++) {
  echo sprintf("%d - %d".PHP_EOL, $i, $j);
}
```

The output of that obviously is:

```
1 - 7
2 - 6
3 - 5
4 - 4
5 - 3
6 - 2
7 - 1
```

*Note: the examples are for CLI usage, for use in a web environment you need to replace the line break from `\n` to `<br>PHP_EOL`*.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if I understand what are you looking for, but I think that should be a solution:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; //or $array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

public function getNumberNotReversed($array, $number) {
    return $array[$number - 1];
}

public function getNumberReversed($array, $number) {
    return array_reverse($array)[$number - 1];
}

echo getNumberNotReversed($array, 2); //print 2 (base 7 or 8)
echo PHP_EOL;
echo getNumberReversed($array, 2); //print 6 (base 7), print 7 (base 8)
```

Hope I understand well.